# Spring MVC 3 - object persistence between multiple controllers and views

Tags: session, spring-mvc, data-persistence

I have the following scenario in my application.

There are multiple controllers and views. There is no login/logout functionality and no traditional username/password stuff. The application does some logic on incoming requests directly (no authentication/authorization).

As the user goes through controllers and views, I need to persist the user specific data at some place. This is needed as I need to refer to this until the user is completely out of the application. Basically I need to persist user data without any authentication/authorization functionality.

Shall I go for the traditional HttpSession or Spring's @SessionAttribute to store the required details? Or is there any other better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!